# How to change the icon from the executable generated from an E4 RCP product?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have a standalone application in Eclipse 4 RCP.

When exporting it as a product, as shown below:

[image: Export wizard]

The following structure is generated:

[image: Generated structure]

How to change the icon of the executable aplicacao.exe?

I already tried to put images in the Launching tab of the .product file, but without success.

[image: Launching tab]

Comment: Did you use `*.bmp` images? If yes, make sure the BMP files do not have color space information and are 24 bit (R8 G8 B8).

Comment: Yes, I tried with separate .bmp images as specified by Eclipse and with a .ico file created with icofx software. Do you have a .ico file that works to compare with mine?

Comment: If using an `*.ico` file, the 256x256 image in it must be uncompressed. Example: https://sourceforge.net/p/pacx/code/HEAD/tree/net.sf.pacx/graphics/pacx.ico or the original `eclipse.ico`: http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git/plain/eclipse.platform.releng.tychoeclipsebuilder/platform/icons/eclipse.ico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With [this icon](https://sourceforge.net/p/pacx/code/HEAD/tree/net.sf.pacx/graphics/pacx.ico?format=raw)** file you can **find out** if the problem is **caused by the icon file or by the `*.product` file**:

- If it doesn't work even with this icon file, try to **create a new `*.product` file** from scratch.
- If it works, make sure in your **[ICO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format))** file, the **256×256**-pixel image **is stored uncompressed**, not as compressed PNG.

**OBS:** Maybe it's a icon **cache** problem. Change the **Launcher Name** in the **`.product`** **Launching tab** or **rebuild the OS's icon cache** can solve the problem.

Comment: How do you uncompress a png file? I tried GIMP, putting the compression level to 0, but Eclipse does not recognize it.

Comment: If using Gimp, try to open the [`eclipse.ico`](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git/plain/eclipse.platform.releng.tychoeclipsebuilder/platform/icons/eclipse.ico) and export (Ctrl+Shift+E) it as `demo.ico` with all _compress_ checkboxes unchecked. Do only use the sizes which are used in the `eclipse.ico` file.

Comment: I imported eclipse.ico, colored the images to differ from the original, exported as .ico with all checkboxes unchecked and didn't work.

Comment: Does it work if you do not change anything, just export it to a new file? If no, does [this icon](https://sourceforge.net/p/pacx/code/HEAD/tree/net.sf.pacx/graphics/pacx.ico?format=raw) work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I don't know, because the Eclipse icon is the default. The pacx icon also didn't work, I'm thinking the problem is not with the images.

Comment: Maybe your `.product` file is broken or something is going wrong on exporting it. Could you try to export the product via the _Eclipse Product export wizard_ link on the _Overview_ page in the product editor? If this does not fix your issue, try to create a new simple `.product` file.

Comment: Export the product via Eclipse Product Export on the Overview tab didn't work, but I created a new project with the demo application and the icon change worked.

Comment: Maybe you can find the issue by comparing both product files.

Comment: I didn't find the problem cause, but I created a new workspace for my projects and it's working now. Please edit your answer with the summary of our discussion so I can mark your answer as the one that solved my problem. If you prefer I do the editing and submit for your review.

Comment: @KevinEduardPiske Great. I edited the answer, but corrections and improvements are always welcome.